# L6384: Expected waveforms on boot pin

Tags: dc-motor, mosfet-driver, bootstrap

Here my driver section using [L6384](https://www.mouser.it/datasheet/2/389/stmicroelectronics_cd00001381-1204670.pdf):

[image]

`SD1` and `SD2` are at 0V.
On `IN1` and `IN2` I apply some square waveforms 0..5V

On pin 8 `VBOOT` I read a fixed voltage of about 7V.
On pin 6 `OUT` I read a fixed voltage of 0V and also on the other output pins 5 and 7 I don't see any activities.

What is the expected waveform on pins 6 and 8?

My board has 3 identical sections, and I have a couple of boards. All show the same behavior. And of course the motors don't run...

Comment: From the datasheet about the DT/SD pin: `When pulled lower than Vdt [Typ. 0.5V] the
device is shut down. ` So if you're at 0V, your device is shut down...

Comment: @Ron  Nope. I said `SD1` and `SD2` are at 0V. That means the BJTs are off and the R is connected to the driver, as expected.

Comment: `The dead time value can be set forcing a certain voltage
level on the pin or connecting a resistor between pin 3 and ground`

Comment: On pin 3 I read about 3V by the way.

Comment: You might get better responses if you [redrew your image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXaIq.png) to be kinder on the eyes.

Comment: @Andyaka last time I sent an image with darker color and you said I cannot post such an image. Now I tried inverting the colors and I failed again...

Comment: It's ok for you now?

Comment: There’s no BJTs in your circuit. What is the frequency of the ‘square waves’ you apply?

Comment: OK I here you but it was the excessive width that made it really hard to read the details within the limited space available on this site (unless you have a big screen). The image I linked I shortened for you but, it could still be less wide in order to give those with poor eyes a better chance.

Comment: @Kartman my bad, of course I was talking about MOSFETs Q13 and Q24

Comment: The PWM frequency is 1 kHz but I tried with lower and higher frequency as well. No changes in the description above.